How Create CloudWatch Disk Space Alarm for Different Paths Dynamically
I have configured CW agent to send disk space metrics and create an alarm based on that metric.
I'm using terraform deploy resources in AWS. Below code is working when I only create alarm for a single path like /var.
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "EC2_DiskSpace_Alert" {
  count               = terraform.workspace == "prod"  ? var.instance_count : 0 
  alarm_name          = "${terraform.workspace}_${var.name}_${count.index}_EC2_DiskSpace_Alert"
  alarm_description   = "Alert when Disk Space Utilization is above threshold"
  alarm_actions       =  [data.aws_sns_topic.cloudwatch_alerts.arn]
  metric_name         = "disk_used_percent"
  namespace           = "CWAgent"
  statistic           = "Average"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  threshold           = 70
  unit                = "Percent"
  evaluation_periods  = 3
  period              = 5
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  tags = {
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }

  dimensions = {
    "InstanceId"   = aws_instance.i[count.index].id
  }
}

But if I want to create an alarm for each path like /var, / code should be like this.
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "EC2_DiskSpace_Alert" {
  count               = terraform.workspace == "prod"  ? var.instance_count : 0 
  alarm_name          = "${terraform.workspace}_${var.name}_${count.index}_EC2_DiskSpace_Alert"
  alarm_description   = "Alert when Disk Space Utilization is above threshold"
  alarm_actions       =  [data.aws_sns_topic.cloudwatch_alerts.arn]
  metric_name         = "disk_used_percent"
  namespace           = "CWAgent"
  statistic           = "Average"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  threshold           = 70
  unit                = "Percent"
  evaluation_periods  = 3
  period              = 5
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  tags = {
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }

  dimensions = {
    "InstanceId"   = aws_instance.i[count.index].id
    "ImageId"      = "ami-xx"
    "InstanceType" = "t2-micro"
    "path"         = "/var"
    "device"       = "mapper"
    "fstype"       = "xfs"

  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "EC2_DiskSpace_Alert" {
  count               = terraform.workspace == "prod"  ? var.instance_count : 0 
  alarm_name          = "${terraform.workspace}_${var.name}_${count.index}_EC2_DiskSpace_Alert"
  alarm_description   = "Alert when Disk Space Utilization is above threshold"
  alarm_actions       =  [data.aws_sns_topic.cloudwatch_alerts.arn]
  metric_name         = "disk_used_percent"
  namespace           = "CWAgent"
  statistic           = "Average"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  threshold           = 70
  unit                = "Percent"
  evaluation_periods  = 3
  period              = 5
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  tags = {
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }

  dimensions = {
    "InstanceId"   = aws_instance.i[count.index].id
    "ImageId"      = "ami-xx"
    "InstanceType" = "t2-micro"
    "path"         = "/"
    "device"       = "mapper"
    "fstype"       = "xfs"

  }
}

Is there a better way to do it without repeating this block for each path that I want to create an alarm? Like creating a dynamic "dimensions" without hardcoding values?
Thank you in advance.

You need to create a new CloudWatch alarm (a new Terraform resource) for each path. Using a dynamic block for each path wouldn't work, because it would just create a single alarm with multiple dimensions. An alarm can only have one dimensions block anyway, so you would just get an error if you tried that.
You could use for_each with a list of the paths. But you can't use for_each with count. It may be cleaner to just do it how it is now. How many actual disks are you attaching to the instances anyway? You don't need an alarm for every path on a disk, just an alarm for each disk.

@MarkB  Thank you for the quick reply.
Regarding for_each, is it possible to have conditions?I just want to create for a certain terraform workspace like the one in the count?
Unfortunately it's a requirement to monitor certain paths around 10 paths.

You would use a locals block to create the list that for_each uses. In your locals block you would have a condition on terraform.workspace to either create the list with all values, or just create an empty list. If for_each gets an empty list, it's the same as count = 0.

for_each = terraform.workspace == "prod" ? local.paths : [] - but if it`s not too late I would consider writing a module for creating EC2 instances with all required alarms and other resources.

Thank all for the suggestions.
I was able to make it work using for_each and locals.
locals {
  paths = {
    "root" : {
      "path"   = "/",
      "device" = "xvda1",
      "fstype" = "ext4",
    },
    "boot_efi" : {
      "path"   = "/boot/efi",
      "device" = "xvda15",
      "fstype" = "vfat",
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "warning_ec2_diskspace_alert" {
  for_each            = terraform.workspace == "dev" || terraform.workspace == "prod" ? local.paths : {}
  alarm_name          = "${terraform.workspace}_${each.key}_warning_ec2_diskspace_alert"
  alarm_description   = "Alert when Disk Space Utilization is above threshold"
  metric_name         = "disk_used_percent"
  namespace           = "CWAgent"
  statistic           = "Average"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  threshold           = 70
  unit                = "Percent"
  evaluation_periods  = 3
  period              = 60
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  tags = {
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }

  dimensions = {
    "InstanceId"   = aws_instance.web[0].id
    "ImageId"      = aws_instance.web[0].ami
    "InstanceType" = aws_instance.web[0].instance_type
    "path"         = each.value.path
    "device"       = each.value.device
    "fstype"       = each.value.fstype
  }
}

